# Replacing with condition on two files awk

Tags: awk

Using those example:

File1:

```
      rs12124819     1        0.020242          776546 A G
      rs28765502     1        0.022137          832918 T C
       rs7419119     1        0.022518          842013 T G
        rs950122     1        0.022720          846864 G C
```

File2:

```
1_752566    1   0   752566  G   A
1_776546    1   0   776546  A   G
1_832918    1   0   832918  T   C
1_842013    1   0   842013  T   G
```

I am trying to change the 1st column of file2 with the corresponding 1st column of file1 if their 4th column are equal.

Expected output:

```
rs12124819  1   0   752566  G   A
rs28765502  1   0   776546  A   G
rs7419119   1   0   832918  T   C
rs950122    1   0   842013  T   G
```

I tried to create 2 array but couldn't find the correct way to use it:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4],b[$1];next} ($4) in a{$1=b[FNR]}1' file1 file2  > out.txt
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So clearly you asked a different problem but showed incorrect sample data or expected output. I suggest you fix your question to clear confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$1;next} ($4 in a){$1=a[$4]} 1' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '            ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{         ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  a[$4]=$1       ##Creating array a whose index is $4 and value is $1.
  next           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($4 in a){       ##Checking condition if 4th field is present in a then do following.
  $1=a[$4]       ##Setting value of 1st field of file2 as array a value with index of 4th column
}
1                ##1 will print edited/non-edited line.
' file1 file2    ##mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot ! It works perfectly too, just to be sure, the `a[$4]=$1` do create some kind of dictionnary with key/value and you access the value by specifying the key there  `a[$4]` ? Thanks again !

Comment: @Cagami, yes please if you see my explanation carefully, I have explained it there. `a[$4]=$1` is like a key value pair logic only. Its creating array a with index of 4th field($4) and value it 1st field($1), let me know in case of any more queries here.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 ,I have been using your method and it works as expected but I would like to know if you know how to add another condition. For example in this example if I would like to add another condition on top of the pre-existing one which is:
$2 file1 = $2 file2.  I did try using this command but it does not work as the value is always found in the dico.

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$1; b[$2]=$1; next} ($4 in a && $2 in b){$1=a[$4]} 1' file1 file2`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {map[FNR] = $1; next} {$1 = map[FNR]} 1' file1 file2 | column -t

rs12124819  1  0  752566  G  A
rs28765502  1  0  776546  A  G
rs7419119   1  0  832918  T  C
rs950122    1  0  842013  T  G
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot ! The output is the one expected thanks. However, do you mind explaining where do you check the 4th column value in that command?

Comment: It is a bit unclear on matching 4th column. e.g. `752566` exists only in 2nd file but not in 1st file

Answer (score 1):

another alternative (if the files are sorted in the join key as in the sample data)

```
$ join -j4 -o1.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6 file1 file2  | column -t

rs12124819  1  0  776546  A  G
rs28765502  1  0  832918  T  C
rs7419119   1  0  842013  T  G
```

Note that your input files have only 3 matching records.