# Unix replacing values with 2 conditions from 2 files

Tags: awk

I am having an issue that I almost solved thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997850/replacing-with-condition-on-two-files-awk). Using a dataset in the same format:

File 1

```
     32074_32077     1        0.008348          834830 G A
     32082_32085     1        0.008349          834928 A G
     32085_32088     2        0.008350          834928 G A
     32903_32906     5        0.008468          846808 C T
```

File 2

```
       rs3094315     1        0.020130          752566 G A
      rs12124819     1        0.020242          834928 A G
      rs28765502     2        0.022137          834928 T C
       rs7419119     3        0.022518          846808 T G
```

I would like to change the 1st column of file one only IF $4 and $2 are the same in FILE2. If it is not I would like to keep the line as it is.

Expected output:

```
     32074_32077     1        0.008348          834830 G A
     rs12124819      1        0.008349          834928 A G
     rs28765502      2        0.008350          834928 G A
     32903_32906     5        0.008468          846808 C T
```

Using the answer from the linked post, I cannot have the expected output. I tried this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$1; b[$2]=$1; next} ($4 in a && $2 in b){$1=a[$4]} 1' file1 file2
```

It doesn't work as expected because the condition `$2 in b` is always true.. I understand but I don't know how I can work around this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2,$4]=$1; next} ($2,$4) in a {$1 = a[$2,$4]} 1' file2 file1 | 
column -t

32074_32077  1  0.008348  834830  G  A
rs12124819   1  0.008349  834928  A  G
rs28765502   2  0.008350  834928  G  A
32903_32906  5  0.008468  846808  C  T
```

Use composite key array `a` with key as `($2,$4)`.

Used `column -t` for showing tabular output.

Comment: Thank you very much, wasn't aware that coud create an array with double keys. Works perfectly.